# Conditional Dynamic Linking

Tags: linux, windows, gcc, linker, clang

This problem is about dynamically loading a specific module depending upon certain condition such as an environment variable and linking function calls to proper modules. The description:

I have module M1 which needs to use module `M2` or `M3` depending upon an environment variable. It is like both modules `M2` and `M3` provide a function `f()`. Here are two different issues:

1. `M1` wants the `M2::f()` be called if there is certain environment variable set.
2. `M2` wants to call `M3::f()` if the same environment is set. Therefore, `M1::f() ->M2::f() -> M3::f()`
3. If the same variable is not set, `M2` goes out of picture, and `M1`'s calls to `f1()` always ONLY calls `M3::f()`

So, there is requirement that both `M2` and `M3` be loaded simultaneously, but there is problem of indirection.

This is C++ environment and we DO NOT want to use virtual functions.
I am rather looking for some linker solutions that may make this possible.

The application needs to be ported to several OS/hardware platforms but its okay if you could tell me just for Linux and/or Windows.

Any other ideas are also welcome.

Comment: On Windows you can use the linker's delay-loading support to implement this. [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls) has the information you need. [Understanding the Helper Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/understanding-the-helper-function) is relevant. This isn't going to be automatic, though. You will be writing code to implement the indirection.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a simile situation, to save memory and avoid loading of all modules (Plugins) automatically. I used `dlsym` library, and I loaded all the modules on demand. I can share code snippet if this is what you are looking for. You may also get it in internet.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym